# How fast can kernel module handle interrupts?

Tags: kernel, drivers, embedded, interrupt

I'm writing a kernel module on embedded Linux (Yocto distribution), and I wanted to handle some high-frequency interrupts from one of the hardware timers. However, I see that 1us resolution is too high for Linux(?) - I think so because the values are incorrect.
The code is simple:

```
static irqreturn_t pmodule_ref2_irq(int irq, void *lp)
{
        unsigned long int temp;
        ns++;
        temp = ioread32(temp_base_addr + TTC1_INTERRUPT_REGISTER);
        return IRQ_HANDLED;
}
```

Changing Interval value to 100x higher fixes the problem but my resolution is not satisfactory.

My question is: can anyone tell me how fast the **kernel module** Interrupt can be handled, or how can I check it?

Comment: You could look into Linux kernels with a realtime (RT) patch to achieve higher frequency interrupts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latency depends on your final hardware. You can have an idea of what to expect (when using preempt-rt) here:
https://www.osadl.org/Combined-latency-plot-of-all-systems-und.qa-latencyplot-all.0.html?latencies=&showno=&slider=159

Basically, you should expect a maximum latency between 30 to 200 us. That value is including the kernelspace to userspace switch but that can give you an idea.